# How does the function in "this.$store._modules.root" (nuxt) work?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Hello I am start studing javascript and vue :) 
( I am sorry if my question is too silly or my English is too bad.)

I tried console.log(this) in nuxt ( becase I was curioused.) 
and i saw very Huge object 
[This is part of that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/co701.png)

I want to know- is any document defined that all value? (vue official site is not record everything)
And want to know how functions work in this.$store._modules.root (ex. forEachChild) 
When I use toString() for see function code- I can see only like this

```
this.$store._modules.root function forEachChild (fn) {
  forEachValue(this._children, fn);
}
```

And I failed looking for that forEachValue... 
Where defined it? Can I see it?

Thank you for reading. have a nice day!

Comment: Usually, attributes prefixed by an underscore are privates and not meant to be used by the end user. You're digging in objects you won't ever have to use haha. But if you're really curious, `this.$store` refers to `Vuex`. The `forEachChild` method is defined here in its [codebase](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/blob/eb52dfa1d5f4120149e7a126fd118311a745e43d/src/module/module.js#L50).

Comment: I didn't know at all! lol Thank you for your kindness Kapcash. and the codebase is an amazing place. also Thank you for this.

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck for your learning :)

Comment: @Kapcash feel free to post your comment as an answer btw.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, **attributes prefixed by an underscore are privates** and not meant to be used by the end user.
You're digging in objects you won't ever have to use haha.

But if you're really curious, `this.$store` refers to Vuex. The `forEachChild` method is defined [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/blob/eb52dfa1d5f4120149e7a126fd118311a745e43d/src/module/module.js#L50) in its codebase.